# Erlang application started with permanent not taking down node or dependencies on shutdown

Tags: erlang

I have a small template project with a single dependency. The behaviour I'm seeking is that when the application is stopped, however it is stopped, its dependencies will be stopped as well and the node will be shut down. In the template project I have a base application called `example` and a dependent application called `depend`. Each has 3 modules: the application (suffixed _app), the primary supervisor (suffixed _sup) and a basic gen_server (suffixed _srv). `depend` is registered in the `{applications` entry in `example.app`.

According to the Erlang docs:

> - If a permanent application terminates, all other applications and the runtime system are also terminated.

Sounds good. That's exactly what I want. I start the application with:

```
application:ensure_all_started(example, permanent).
```

This works well enough. I have each callback log its pid, function name and args to the console:

```
1> application:ensure_all_started(example, permanent).
<0.41.0>: depend_app:start(normal, [])
<0.41.0>: depend_sup:start_link()
<0.42.0>: depend_sup:init([])
<0.42.0>: depend_srv:start_link()
<0.43.0>: depend_srv:init([])
<0.46.0>: example_app:start(normal, [])
<0.46.0>: example_sup:start_link()
<0.47.0>: example_sup:init([])
<0.47.0>: example_srv:start_link()
<0.48.0>: example_srv:init([])
```

So then I call stop:

```
1> application:stop(example).
<0.46.0>: example_app:prep_stop([])
<0.48.0>: example_srv:terminate(shutdown, [])
<0.46.0>: example_app:stop([])
ok
2>
=INFO REPORT==== 3-May-2016::08:22:41 ===
    application: example
    exited: stopped
    type: permanent
2>
```

`depend` is not shut down, and it just sits there at the shell. If I force kill the application with `erlang:exit/2`, for example, then I get the desired behaviour (aside from the crash dump):

```
3> erlang:exit(pid(0,46,0), kill).
true
<0.41.0>: depend_app:prep_stop([])
<0.43.0>: depend_srv:terminate(shutdown, [])
<0.41.0>: depend_app:stop([])
4>
=INFO REPORT==== 3-May-2016::09:02:04 ===
    application: example
    exited: killed
    type: permanent
4> {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_terminated,example,killed}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_terminated,example,killed})

D:\dev\app_test>
```

But why not when shutting down normally? It seems to be behaving as a `transient` or `temporary` application, not as I would expect `permanent` based on what's written in the docs.

One additional note, I am version locked to erts-5.10.4/otp-R16B03-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a bit lower in the same documentation that you cited is written:

> An application can always be stopped explicitly by calling
>   `application:stop/1`. Regardless of the mode, no other applications are
>   affected.

You are correct then that it works only when the application is stopped abnormally, e.g. killed. See [this code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.3.2/lib/kernel/src/application_controller.erl#L1395) - the first thing OTP does when stopping an application is unlinking the process and deleting info that the application is running. Since a [process terminated normally](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id86737) doesn't generate any signals that could be received by other processes, this can lead to a conclusion that the detection if dependent applications should be stopped depends on a link between the `application_controller` and the running application.

Comment: Boy, that's interesting. Thanks for the heads up. I didn't make that connection while reading the docs. Is there a preferred way to tear down an OTP application and its dependencies? I've run into application_controller deadlock issues in the past, but now it seems that application:stop/1 is not the way to go.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by tearing down. Normally the applications are running as long as the VM is running. If you need to load/start/stop/unload any applications explicitly you can do that in the applications' `start` and `stop` functions, e.g.: https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/lib/humbundee/src/hbd_app.erl#L30 And you can get all details, including list of dependent applications, from the `.app` file using `application:get_all_key(some_app).` once `some_app` has been loaded.